Multiple Imputation for Multi-level Model with four-levels
I cannot provide reproducible data or code because I am working in a secure environment. However, I can  summarise key parts without issues as I have some information outputted securely.
I am trying (and failing) to conduct a multi-level longitudinal logistic regression model:
Random-effects: person_id, wave (unbalanced), and school_id nested in area_id
Outcome: education_met - binary yes or no
Covariates: 14 in total - mix of continuous, ordinal and binary variables; some are centred to help the model run.
Sample size: 200,000~ over 2 - 4 time-points heavily unbalanced.
The complete-case model worked fine - using glmmTMB as glmer did not converge - but to check our estimates I want to complete multiple imputation to ensure that our estimates when imputed match the complete-case as we have 20% missingness. I've been working with the mice and miceadds package but I've had no luck - mitml only accepts one random-effect (as I logged an issue) but says the other packages specified will do the job.
I've settled on 2l.pmm from the miceadds package as the binary model seems too demanding and the binary package from mice failed anyway due to relying on glmer - when I used glmmTMB for convergence and speed. I know there are issues with pmm but it seems to be the best option I have from what I have read.
I have got this far but after a few weeks of trouble, I have hit a wall:
Imp < data %>% select(person_id, wave, school_id, area_id, y, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11)

pred[c("y", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10", "x11"), c("person_id", "wave", "school_id", "area_id")] <- -2 

imp <- mice(data, method = "2l.pmm, pred=pred, maxit=1, m=1)


The code continues to fail due to a host of things depending on what I try:

Using formula(x) is deprecated when x is a character vector of length > 1
Error in z0 * u: non-conformable arrays
In commonArgs(par, fn, control, environment()): maxfun < N * length(par)^2 is not recommended.

Following this - mice does not run.
Any help would be very appreciated as I am out of methods, and starting to come back to forums/posts/R packages I have already seen before and tried.

Adding a comment instead of an answer because I am not directly answering the question. However, I recommend checking at the following for the type of data you dealing with. We've just launched Scikit-Longitudinal. A collection of longitudinal-based machine learning classifiers that comprehend the temporality from the ground up and do not use mixed effect models necessarily. https://www.github.com/simonprovost/scikit-longitudinal, and an Automated Machine Learning variant: https://www.github.com/simonprovost/auto-sklong
